ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Multiple commands produce '/Users/Documents/XXX/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
I have implemented the solutions outlined in this post: (ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Privacy).
However, upon adding PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy and attempting to build, I encounter the following error:
Multiple commands produce '/Users/XXX/Documents/XXX/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy'

To address this issue, I referred to another solution provided here: (Multiple commands produce error in Xcode 13).
However, removing PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy from "Copy Bundle Resources" also removes its association with the target. Consequently, there's no connection to the target.
Could someone please provide a solution specifically tailored to handling PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy?

Is your project a native iOS project? Or a React Native/Flutter?

@tomerpacific RN

RN still hasn't released support for Privacy Manifest...https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/discussions/776#discussion-6437392

ReactNative still hasn't released support for Privacy Manifest...
https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/discussions/776

This should have been a comment instead of answer.

@PrateekVarshney people can take a look at answer directly so posted as an answer. Wll update once there is any solution
